# ListView SelectAll() will not update properly

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two listviews. **ListView A** gets its items from one database(that works just fine) and **ListView B** gets its items from the selected items in ListView A. That also works fine, if I manually select all the items in ListView A.

The issue that I am having is:
I have a button that is supposed to select all items in ListView A and by that load all Items that belong to ListView A in ListViewB.

The code I have for the button now is this:

```
private void cmd_SelectAll_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (object o in TransformerList.Items)
        {
                TransformerList.SelectedItems.Add(o);
                //I have also tried TransformerList.SelectAll();
        }  
    }
```

When I click the button, it selects all the items in the ListView, but it doesn't seem to update correctly. So it gives ListView B, the disproportionate amount of items. If I then unselect and reselect an item in ListView A, it gives the correct amount of ListView B.

I hope I have explained well enough, and that someone has an idea of how to fix this.

Thank you for your help :)

EDIT:
It seems like it is just updating the Items that are currently visible before you scroll down. So if I make ListViewA larger, it will add more items to ListViewB.

Comment: If it correctly selects all items in your ListView, then apparently *that* code is working just fine. What are you doing with B then; because that’s what’s failing here?

Comment: how is second list displaying the items. Give the itemSource details, xaml + data(viewmodel if)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. Basically, all the items in the listview that are not in view, return null. So I just had to set

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False"
```

in my listview xaml.

Then the listview will update properly

Comment: Be aware, that this may cause serious performance issues if your listview contains many items.

Comment: @derpirscher, Yes I realize but my listview will never contain more than a couple of hundrer items as far as I know. I have tested and there doesnt seem to be any issues. And it is, as far as I know, the only way to make it work. But thank you for your concern :)

Comment: You could add an additional property in your data and bind that one to the IsSelected property of a ListViewItem. Thus, to change the selection status you don't manipulate the SelectedItems Collection but the IsSelected property of the dataitem.